# Hi I am trying to show a interstitial ads on my app but there is an error?

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show interstitial ads on my app but I am getting this error and I am not even sure if this is the error that is causing my app to not load the ads...
pls, help...

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.xyz.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@d70cda7[MainActivity] that was originally added here
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:733)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:717)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:399)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:340)
       at com.itsmypac.xand0.MainActivity.Player1(MainActivity.java:137)
       at com.itsmypac.xand0.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

And I am also getting this error

```
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_32.bin': No such file or directory
    Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
    Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
    Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/icudtl.dat': No such file or directory
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/chrome_100_percent.pak': No such file or directory
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
I/chatty: uid=10168(com.itsmypac.xand0) identical 1 line
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
    Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/resources.pak': No such file or directory
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/stored-locales/en-US.pak': No such file or directory
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_32.bin': No such file or directory
E/.itsmypac.xand: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
    Failed to open file '/data/data/com.itsmypac.xand0/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin': No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's not an error its a warning.  It won't cause a crash, and its unlikely (although not impossible) to be the cause of your problem.  It basically means you have a view created on that line that wasn't in the root view when the activity was destroyed and may have caused a memory leak.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have also added one more error that was coming, can you pls check and tell if that is the error that is causing ads not to show up

Comment: @EwanKoster - what is code written on this line ? MainActivity.java:137